# python/discord.py - How can I edit a JSON file value without overwriting all of the other values?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot with Python. I'm using a JSON file to store settings for the servers my bot is in. (ex: modules). When someone runs the /level toggle command, it modifies the 'level_module' value from 0 to 1. (0 is on, 1 is off.). It does work, but there is one problem: **It clears every other value.** I want the values to be intact, If a user has the moderation module disabled (1), and someone toggles a module, that value shouldn't go back to 0. It should **only** edit that value. I've searched for a long time on the internet to find out how to edit this value without removing all other values or changing it, and I found no answer. Any idea? Please and thank you.

REMEMBER: It should **ONLY** edit that value, not everything else. What shouldn't happen is that if a user has mixed toggles, it shouldn't go to its defaults when a module is toggled.

Code:

```
levelmds = app_commands.Group(name="leveling", description="Toggle leveling cmds")

@levelmds.command(name="toggle", description="Toggle the leveling module.")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def count_steam(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await interaction.response.send_message(":x: Only administrators can execute this command.")
    else:
            with open("database\\wae.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                data = json.load(f)
            if str(interaction.guild.id) in data:
                lvlmod = data[str(interaction.guild.id)]['level_module']
                if lvlmod == 0:
                    with open("database\\wae.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                        data = json.load(f)
                    data[str(interaction.guild.id)] = {}
                    data[str(interaction.guild.id)]['level_module'] = 1
                    with open("database\\wae.json", "w+") as fa:
                        json.dump(data, fa)
                    await interaction.response.send_message("✅ Successfully disabled the Leveling module.")
                else:
                    with open("database\\wae.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                        data = json.load(f)
                    data[str(interaction.guild.id)] = {}
                    data[str(interaction.guild.id)]['level_module'] = 0
                    with open("database\\wae.json", "w+") as fa:
                        json.dump(data, fa)
                    await interaction.response.send_message("✅ Successfully enabled the Leveling module.")                 


bot.tree.add_command(levelmds)
```

My JSON file:

```
{"1172011084274733076": {"level_module": 0, "moderation_module": 0, "test": 1}}
```

Result after executing the command:

[image]

Text format:

```
{"1172011084274733076": {"level_module": 1}}
```

Comment: That's not how files work. If you change a value, it usually changes the length of the file. All the data needs to shift around. The right solution is usually to rewrite the entire file back to disk. Open the file, read its data, modify the data, and overwrite the file.

Comment: Its removing **all of the values**, its not shifting around

Comment: My point is that files don't work the way data structures do in programming languages. Overwriting the file in full is usually the right solution.

Comment: But that would cause several problems, like if a user has the moderation module off, and when someone disables the leveling module, the moderation module is enabled again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new dictionary with the line:

```
data[str(interaction.guild.id)] = {}
```

So that's why you are losing the other keys.

---

Anyway, I **highly recommend you to use a database instead of a JSON file** because, if the bot receives a lot of traffic, there may be problems. If you like how JSON files work, you may try MongoDB.